# How to hide a public method?

Tags: java, annotations, scope, public-method

I have a method in my static state machine that is only used once when my application is first fired up. The method needs to be public, but I still want it hidden. Is there a way to use an annotation or something that will hide the method from the rest of the project?

Comment: maybe just name it something blatant - like OnlyUseThisOnStartup();

Comment: Why do you want it to be both **public** and **hidden**? In other words, how could that would benefit you?

Comment: Make the method throw an exception if the method is called a second time?

Comment: Where exactly should it be visible and where hidden? Maybe `default` will do? If it's a initializer just put it in `static{}` block.

Comment: @Randy & Mannimarco - I could do both of those, and that is the easiest solution, I was just curious if there was a subtle solution.

Comment: What do you mean by hiding? Just hiding for code completion features in the IDE, or to really prevent others from calling it.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - Hide it in the IDE / Docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you declare public method it becomes part of your class's contract. You can't hide it because all class users will expect this method to be available.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot make a public method hidden (unless you can declare it private). You can however put in a subclass and only let the users of the object know the type of the superclass, that is:

```
class A {
   //Externally visible members
}

class B extends A {
   //Secret public members
}
```

Then you instantiate the class B, but only let the type A be known to others...

Comment: Do not hack your way through this with reflection. It will come back and haunt you the rest of your life if you resort to that kind of abuse...

Comment: That is not a reflection hack.  That is a legitimate OOP design.

Comment: Yes, this was a comment to my own posting. I will simply recommend against the reflection hacking that others are proposing on this page.

Comment: Actually, I found this suggestion is the most useful. Although the question was about how to hide a public method, but the intention was probably how to keep a method accessible internally while the outer world won't be aware of them. However, you can always define an interface instead of a class which contains only the methods which are meant for the external access.

Answer (score 1):

You could use package level instead of public.  That way it can only be called by your application.

Answer (score 1):

If a method is public, it can't be hidden. What you may really be looking for is just a way to restrict access to calling a method. There are other ways to achieve a similar effect.

If there are some things that your state machine does that are "only used once when my application is first fired up" it sounds a lot like those are things that could happen in the constructor. Although it depends on how complex those tasks are, you may not want to do that at construction time.

Since you said your state machine is static, is it also a **Singleton**? You could maybe use the [Singleton Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html).

```
public class SimpleStateMachine {

  private static SimpleStateMachine instance = new SimpleStateMachine();

  private SimpleStateMachine() {
      super();
      System.out.println("Welcome to the machine");  // prints 1st
  }

  public static SimpleStateMachine getInstance() {
      return instance;
  }

  public void doUsefulThings() {
      System.out.println("Doing useful things");  // prints 3rd
  }
}
```

Here's some code for a client of this Singleton:

```
public class MachineCaller {

    static SimpleStateMachine machine = SimpleStateMachine.getInstance();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Start at the very beginning");  // prints 2nd
        machine.doUsefulThings();
    }
}
```

Note that the `SimpleStateMachine` instance isn't built until the first time your class is accessed. Because it's declared as `static` in the `MachineCaller` client, that counts as a "first access" and creates the instance.  Keep this tidbit in mind if you definitely want your state machine to perform some of those initialization tasks at the time your application starts up.

So, if you don't want to turn your state machine class into a true singleton... you can use a [static initialization block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) do your one-time tasks the first time the class is accessed. That would look something like this:

```
public class SimpleStateMachine {

    static {
        System.out.println("First time tasks #1");
        System.out.println("First time tasks #2");
    }

    public SimpleStateMachine() {
        super();
        System.out.println("Welcome to the machine");
    }

    public void doUsefulThings() {
        System.out.println("Doing useful things");
    }
}
```

While we're at it, since you mentioned that it's a state machine... the [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) book does a nice, easily understandable treatment of the [State Pattern](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/patterns/0596007124/the-state-of-things/hfdesignpat-chp-10-sect-11). I recommend reading it if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic approach to doing this is to use interfaces to limit the visibility of your methods.

For example, say you have the following class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void method1() {
        // ...
    }
    public void method2() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you want to limit some parts of the project to only see `method1()`, then what you do is describe it in an interface, and have the class implement that interface:

```
public interface Method1Interface {
    public void method1();
}

...

public class MyClass implements Method1Interface {
    public void method1() {
        // ...
    }
    public void method2() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, you can limit the visibility of the methods by choosing to pass the class around either as a `MyClass` reference, or as a `Method1Interface` reference:

```
public class OtherClass {
    public void otherMethod1(MyClass obj) {
        // can access both obj.method1() and obj.method2()
    }
    public void otherMethod2(Method1Interface obj) {
        // can only access obj.method1(), obj.method2() is hidden.
    }
}
```

A bonus of this approach is that it can also be easily extended. Say, for example, you now also want to independently control access to `method2()`. All you need do is create a new `Method2Interface` along the same lines as `Method1Interface`, and have `MyClass` implement it. Then, you can control access to `method2()` in exactly the same manner as `method1()`.

This is a similar approach to that advocated in [@MathiasSchwarz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6751765/214149), but is much more flexible:

- The independent access control described in the preceding paragraph isn't possible with Mathias' technique, due to Java not supporting multiple inheritance.
- Not requiring an inheritance relationship also allows more flexibility in designing the class hierarchy.
- The only change required to the original class is to add `implements Method1Interface`, which means that it is a *very* low-impact refactor since existing users of `MyClass` don't have to be changed at all (at least, until the choice is made to change them to use `Method1Interface`).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution: You can make it `private` and create a `invokeHiddenMethod(String methodName, Object ... args)` method using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... You want a private method, but want to access it outside?

Try do this with reflection. 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You said that your public method is used only once when the application is started up.

Perhaps you could leave the method public, but make it do nothing after the first call?

Answer (score 0):

There is a (non-)keyword level *package level visibility*. Instead of public, protected, or private, you use nothing.

This would make the method or class visible to the class and others in the package, but would give you a certain modicum of privacy. You may want to look at [What is the use of package level protection in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403583/what-is-the-use-of-package-level-protection-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many Java programmers do something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
      new MyClass();
}
```

So basically they create just one object of the class. If there is a method which should run only once, I guess this approach can achieve that. Your method will be called from inside the constructor. But since I don't know how your app works, what are the constraints, so it is just a thought.