# Restricting public accessable members - workaround

Tags: java, oop, visibility

I want to break my applications model in the logical parts 'Data', 'Commands' and 'Engines'. Everyone outside the application should get a read-only access to the data and access to the commands. With these commands they can manipulate the data.

Of this I have sturctured my application in the packages:

```
myapp.model.data
myapp.model.commands
myapp.model.engines
```

Both the engines and the commands needs a write access to the data. Hence I have to expose a write access in form of an public interface. This leads to the problem that external clients also have a write access to my data, which can not be allowed. The problem with this would be, that the commands calls with events the engines to check the consistence of the data. The clients would manipulate the data without calling the engines and thereby break the consistence of the data.

Is there a common pratice of this problem. Please do not suggest I have to wait until Java 8, because I want to write my application now. Throwing all classes in one package is also no option because I would lose the overview of my application.

**Edit**

I read through some sites about immutability of trees and graphs. I have seen a nice idea called zipper: http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2010/01/13/zippers-making-functional-upda/. Unfortunately this does not seem to work for my case.

To recall, I have a complex object graph structure which will be manipulated over time. The goal was to restrict the client to manipulate the data only with my commands. Therefore I dont see the advantage of immutability in my case.

For this I give the data classes two public interfaces a readonly an a writeable. Whenever the client calls a command with a readonly instance I just have to cast it to the writeable instance. This approache solves my problem but has two big disadvantages. First I assume that every readonly instance is a writeable instance at the same time - this could lead to some ugly bugs. Second the client could do the same and have a write access. But than I could say its their own fault.

Has somebody a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three patterns that I pull on for this type of problem. In approximate order that I try them in:

1) Go immutable/side effect free. A technique heavily recommended by functional programming languages, and java.lang.String is an example of. Here a single instance is not mutable, and calls to mutate create a new instance. May not work with how you designed the interfaces to your commands and engines, but if you have the energy to redesign their interfaces then this is a very powerful approach which tends to reduce line count.

2) Lockable object pattern. An object is mutable when first created, but it is 'locked' before being shared. After being locked any call to a mutating method errors. Unlocking an object involves creating a new copy of the object.

3) Create a read only wrapper for a mutable instance. This allows you to control who can mutate, and who can read only. java.util.Collections#unmodifiableList(List list) is an example from the Java Runtime of this decorator style pattern that keeps the setter methods on the shared interface. One can use a different interface that does not have the setter methods on at all.

My preference is always 1, as it leads to simpler code that is easier to scale. However if I have trouble with that then I tend to fall back onto 2 as it gives a balance between the approaches and does not allow for the possibility that another thread is mutating an instance behind another threads back. It also does not need that much extra code, but it does require discipline to ensure that objects are locked correctly and enforce the locking semantics. As such it is not a very common pattern in practice.

Comment: I like the idea of immutable classes. The problem here is that my data is in a tree structure and serves as datasource for the UI. I will look into this and try finding a good solution. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Redesigning for immutable data structures can be tricky. There is a pattern used by Clojure that is backed by a hash trie that can be used for your kind of case. It involves using an immutable hash map to implement the tree. Probably over kill for you here though, but it is an interesting read. http://blog.higher-order.net/2009/09/08/understanding-clojures-persistenthashmap-deftwice/

Comment: What would be the advantage of immutability here. My data changes over time, therefore is not immutable.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a common limitation of folders (tree like structure).
Solutions:

1. Make sure you document data should not be accessed (JavaDoc).
2. If you want to go extreme you could check where the call is coming from and deny it (a bit overkill)

As a complement here is a blog post about this subject: [A simple suggestion to radically improve your package structure](http://edmundkirwan.com/general/radial2.html)

Comment: That could be possible, but what I am loking for is a solution where the outer world can only manipulate the data with the commands.

Comment: I think you already know the possible solutions, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403583/what-is-the-use-of-package-level-protection-in-java